# How to remove a setgid directory that links to another location?

Tags: linux, directory, rm, setgid

I use an environment variable $DATAPATH that conveniently takes me to where I store my data. Idk what I did just now but I created a folder in my home directory called '$DATAPATH', and when I cd into it, it takes me to the where my $DATAPATH is. It's like this directory is a shortcut to my actual $DATAPATH folder.

When I run `file` on it, it says the directory is a setgid directory. I'm not sure what that means.

How can I safely remove the shortcut $DATAPATH folder in my home directory, without actually removing anything in my $DATAPATH? The things I store in it are too big to cp/mv around.

Comment: "when I cd into it, it takes me to the where my $DATAPATH is." No it doesn't. You're just not escaping properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you created an ordinary symbolic link and you ran `file $DATAPATH` without single quotes on the folder and not on the symlink which would have given you something like

```
$ file '$DATAPATH'
$DATAPATH: symbolic link to /path/to/xyz
```

You can delete the symlink with

```
rm -i '$DATAPATH'
```

which you will have to confirm with `y` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.